# What is this error I'm getting when I try to generate a Ruby on Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scriptgenerate

I've created controllers in the past successfully, but all of a sudden I'm getting a weird error. I'm doing this:

```
ruby script/generate controller Request
```

And am getting this error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/builder.rb:175:in `build': Illegal route: the :controller must be specified! (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:309:in `add_route'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:317:in `add_named_route'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:57:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/ben/rails_projects/talk/config/routes.rb:55
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:226:in `draw'
    from /Users/ben/rails_projects/talk/config/routes.rb:1
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:286:in `load_routes!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:286:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:286:in `load_routes!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:266:in `reload!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:537:in `initialize_routing'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:188:in `process'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /Users/ben/rails_projects/talk/config/environment.rb:9
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/generate.rb:1
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks for reading.

Comment: i notice your routes.rb page listed in the trace--anything in there that looks suspicious?

Comment: This was it! I somehow missed a half finished line of code in routes.rb, which was causing the problem. Thanks! If you submit an answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what it is, but something in your routes.rb seems to be causing the error

Answer (score 1):

I believe Request is a reserved word and so you can use it as the controller's name.

Have you tried generating another controller with another name to see if the same error occurs?

Comment: Yeah I tried it with some other names and the same error happened.

Comment: oh, really, I can generate the Request controller.

Comment: I've fixed the problem, but I think it might be a good idea to not use Request anyway. Thanks.